# How to change TFS Project version

Tags: tfs

How to change TFS project version and how to use old versions.

I explain my question with an example.

I have a number of projects in solution name is **TestSolution**.(Suppose solution version is 1.0)

I create publishing file of the solution suppose 10-Dec-2013 and publish to Client (we are changing version 1.0 to 1.1).

After that we are modifying the project, On 15-Dec-2013 the client asking for a small change that change will fit in Version 1.0 then we need to create a new publishing file on Version 1.0. Is it possible on TFS 2010? And merge the change form on Version 1.1?

Comment: Not completely sure what you're asking here.  TFS will store changes to a project file, providing you include that file in source control.  You haven't said what type of project / solution you're dealing with: web site, web application, WPF, winforms, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can branch a directory in source by date or changeset.

**To branch by date or changeset:**
1.In Source Control Explorer, right-click the folder or file that you want to branch, point to Branching and Merging, and then click Branch.

- The Branch dialog box appears.

2.In the Target box, modify the location and name for the new branch.

- You can also click Browse to specify a target.

3.In the Branch from version section, click one of the following options in the By list:

- If you click Changeset, you can specify the number of the changeset in the Changeset box. As an alternative, you can click the ellipses (…) to open the Find Changesets dialog box.

  -If you click Date, you can specify a date in the Date box.

I would suggest you look at using [labels on your source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181439%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) when you release.  It gives you the ability to have an exact marker of your source to branch from in the future if needed.